# Application root directory changing in Xamarin.ios

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xamarin.ios

I created the application and stored the database in the root directory of the ios app.
Like

var documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);

var  retVal = Path.Combine(documentsPath, "..", "Library");

retval gets the path I store the database and as well as images in respective directory for inside the app root folder. but suddenly I am suffering from the issue where Application folder gets updated with new GUID / app ID. Because of this I am not able to access the images. If anyone know about the fix of this issue then please answer.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: iOS apps run in a sandbox. You can not use absolute paths. You have to fetch the documents directory path at runtime see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilemanager/1407726-urlsfordirectory

Comment: This also means you should only store relative paths, not absolute paths

Comment: Thanks. How can we achieve this in xamarin.ios ? Also is there any way for backward compatibility?

Comment: In Xamrin.ios, you can try to use the [GetDirectoryRoot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getdirectoryroot?view=net-7.0) method to get the changed root directory and then re-get the file path.

Comment: I presume that there is some way to call the native libraries in Xamarin. What do you mean by "backward compatibility"? This function has been available since iOS 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store your database data in the `Documents` and `Library` directories.

In iOS, When a new version of your application is downloaded, iOS creates a new home directory and stores the new Application Bundle in it. iOS then moves the `Documents` and `Library` folders from the previous version of your Application Bundle to your new home directory.

For more information, please refer to the official document: [File system access in Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/file-system#application-version-updates)